# Left-hand side of assignment must be a variable

Tags: java

It seems like a lot of people have this issue when they use CharAt statements, but I'm having trouble implementing simple stuff like (a + 1).

My Code:

```
public class Problem1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 1;
    int x = 0;

            while (a < 1000)
                if 
                    ((a + 1)%3 == 0) 
                            (x + a);

                    else if ((a + 1)%5 == 0)
                        (x + a);

                        else (a + 1);
                if (a == 1000)
                    break
                    print x;

}
}
```

My errors occur in the (x + a) then statements and my (a + 1) then statement. I also get a syntax error when trying to print x.

Can someone explain both of these errors to me? Why do they occur?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect (x+a) to do?

Comment: Well, my problem assignment is to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.
With the (x + a), which I have changed to x += a, what I was attempting to do with the x was to add any multiples of 3 and 5 together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't assigning the result of your addition to anything. You are missing a semicolon on `break`. And you didn't increment `a`. The call to `print` is missing parenthesis, but I think you wanted to use `System.out.println()`. And, I recommend you use brackets (even on single line statements). Putting it all together, I believe you wanted something like,

```
while (a < 1000) {
  if ((a + 1) % 3 == 0) {
    x = (x + a);
  } else if ((a + 1) % 5 == 0) {
    x = (x + a);
  } else {
    x = (a + 1);
  }
  if (a == 1000) {
    break; // <-- missing semicolon.
  }
  System.out.println(x); // <-- print.
  a++; // <-- increment a.
}
```

Finally, you could use an `or` and you could use `+=` like

```
while (a < 1000) {
  if ((a + 1) % 3 == 0 || (a + 1) % 5 == 0) { 
    x += a;
  } else { 
    x += a + 1;
  }
  if (a == 1000) {
    break;
  }
  System.out.println(x);
  a++;
}
```

Comment: It would also be useful to add brackets, especially since OP appears to be new and might get tripped up by bracketless one-line `if` blocks.

Comment: @Andrew Agreed. Edited.

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you for helping me understand that. I am now having trouble with the break;. It says "break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch"

Comment: Above it's used (pointlessly) in a `while` loop. The loop will end when `a` is >= 1000

Answer (score 2):

A bit of code such as `(x + a)` by itself is invalid.  You must assign the value too a variable, such as `int n = (x + a)`.

Also, you must have a semicolon `;` after your break statement.

Lastly, there is no `print` statement in Java.  What you are looking for is this:

```
System.out.println(x);
```

Hope that helped, good luck!

Comment: That assignment part was particularly helpful in my understanding of my errors. Thank you!
Also, I knew the system.out.println(x); thing, I just completely spaced on that. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @TravisJ.Land No problem!  Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if your question was answered.